# Align listoffigure entries with left border

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation

The entries of `\listoffigures` don't align with the left border of [the body](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout), there's an indent. So, how can I remove it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\subsubsection*{Figures}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\listoffigures{%
        \@starttoc{lof}%
}
\makeatother
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics{example-image-a}
  \caption{A}
  \label{fig:a}
  \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every figure set in the LoF uses `\l@figure` to set the formatting. This formatting under the `article` class is defined as

```
\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}
```

where the arguments of `\@dottedtocline{<level>}{<indent>}{<numwidth>}{<title>}{<page>}` identify

- the `<level>` of the entry being set,
- the `<indent>` from the left margin for that entry,
- the width of the box (`<numwidth>`) that holds the number for that entry,
- the `<title>` for that entry (typically provided by `\caption{<title>}` or `\caption[<LoF entry>]{<title>}`), and
- the `<page>`.

You can obtain the above information by searching the [LaTeX2e source documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/source2e). As you can see, `\l@figure` only supplies the formatting components (the first 3 arguments), that you can adjust to suit your needs. So, adding

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\l@figure}{\@dottedtocline{1}{0pt}{2.3em}}
\makeatother
```

to your preamble (or before calling `\listoffigures`) should remove the indent (set it to `0pt`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\subsubsection*{Figures}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\listoffigures{%
  \@starttoc{lof}%
}
\renewcommand{\l@figure}{\@dottedtocline{1}{0pt}{2.3em}}% Usual indent is 1.5em
\makeatother

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
  \caption{A}% Figure 1
  \caption{B}% Figure 2
  \setcounter{figure}{9}%
  \caption{C}% Figure 10
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

For small application, this type of manual adjustments are sufficient. For a more consistent change on larger projects, consider using tools provided by [`tocloft`](//ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) (where you'd use `\setlength{\cftfigindent}{0pt}` to obtain the same result).

Comment: Yes, `\cftfigindent` works. What macro corresponds to the 3rd parameter of  `\@dottedtocline`?

Comment: @Erwann: `\cftfignumwidth`; look at the [`tocloft` documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/tocloft) for more details.